# ¿Cómo comunicar 2 Componentes de Angular por un servicio?

Tags: angular, typescript

quisiera saber como debo hacer para pasar informacion entre dos componentes de angular ya que tengo un servicio con el siguiente codigo

```js
export class ComunicacionService {

  constructor() { }
  mensaje: any;
  private enviarmensajeSubject = new Subject<any>();
  enviarMensajeObservable = this.enviarmensajeSubject.asObservable();

  enviarMensaje(mensaje: any) {
    this.mensaje = mensaje;
    this.enviarmensajeSubject.next(mensaje);
  }
```

y en el componente emisor para poder transferir el mensaje realizo lo siguiente

```js
Swal.fire(
              'Bienvenido!',
              nickname + ' al modulo Administrador!',
              'success'
            )
            this.router.navigate(['admin'])
             this.comunicacion.enviarMensaje(respuesta);
```

y en el componente que recibe realizo esto

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.comunicacionService.enviarMensajeObservable.subscribe(res => {
      this.idUsuario = res;
      document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = this.idUsuario + "";
    })
```

en el html del componente solo tengo un div de clase id para ver el resultado del mensaje pero no envia o no recibe nada

Comment: Buenas, probá rodear con un setTimeout a document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = this.idUsuario + "". De todas maneras no es buena idea usar esta metodología para angular, deberías usar un  [innerHTML] en el HTML y bindearlo de manera segura.

Comment: Lee este articulo puede que te ayude a encontrar tu respuesta , lee la parte de envio de datos entre servicios y componentes https://medium.com/@javifont/3-formas-de-comunicarse-entre-componentes-angular-b349ada25797

Answer (score 3):

Veo 2 problemas:

1. No es una buena práctica en Angular utilizar APIs del browser para hacer modificaciones en el DOM. En caso de necesitarlo lo mejor es utilizar el `nativeElement`. Puede encontrar un ejemplo [acá](http://blog.enriqueoriol.com/2017/08/angular-dom-renderer.html)
2. Asumo que los 2 components no se cargan al mismo tiempo al momento de la subscripción, así que no se recibe nada. Para solucionar el problema podemos usar un `ReplaySubject` el cual guarda el último valor emitido (o la cantidad que definamos) en cada subscripción.

Servicio para comunicar componentes:

```
@Injectable()
export class ComunicacionService {

  private mensajero = new ReplaySubject<number>(1)
  
  public get recibir() {
    return this.mensajero.asObservable()
  }

  public enviar(id: number): void {
    this.mensajero.next(id);
  }
}
```

La funcion `enviar` recibe un `id` tipo `number` porque segun el ejemplo de la pregunta quieres enviar un `id` pero puede ser cualquier tipo, nada mas tendrías que cambiar el tipo del `ReplaySubject` y el del parametro.

Componente Emisor:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'emisor',
  template: `
    <button (click)="emitirValor()">Enviar valor aleatorio</button>
  `,  
})
export class EmisorComponent  {
  
  constructor(public comunicacion: ComunicacionService) {  }

  public emitirValor() {
    this.comunicacion.enviar(Date.now());
  }
}
```

Componente receptor:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ComunicacionService } from './comunicacion.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'receptor',
  template: `
    Valor Recibido {{ valorEmitido | async }}
  `,  
})
export class ReceptorComponent  {
  
  public valorEmitido = this.comunicacion.recibir;

  constructor(public comunicacion: ComunicacionService) {  }

}
```

Este ultimo componente hace uso del `async` pipe lo cual lo que hace es subscribirse a un observable y obtener el valor desde un view.

Te recomiendo no guarda valores en variables en el servicio dado que cada vez que haga cambio todas sus referencias van ser afectadas.

[Aquí](https://stackblitz.com/edit/es-stackoverflow-303739) puede encontrar el ejemplo completo funcional

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar @Output en el servicio para que sea un eventEmitter.

```
export class ComunicacionService {

  constructor() { }
  mensaje: any;
  @Output enviarmensajeSubject = new EventEmitter<any>();


  enviarMensaje(mensaje: any) {
    this.mensaje = mensaje;
    this.enviarmensajeSubject.emit(mensaje);
  }
```

Cada vez que se ejecute este método emite el evento a los componentes que estén escuchando.
Conforme tienes el componente debería recibir la información, pero recuerda importar de **angular core @Output y EventEmitter** 
Espero que sirva un saludo.

Comment: No, output es para componentes, no servicios

Comment: Buenas, el eventEmitter no está diseñador específicamente para servicios, es mejor utilizar Subject. https://medium.com/@enriqueoriol/angular-service-component-communication-4933782af52c

Comment: influye algo si se cambia de componente es decir es una pagina de login y antes de cambiar de componente envia el mensaje al componente que me enrutara el login

Comment: Hola Pablo el @Output si que funciona en servicios, y Hola Enrique he considerado que es una posible solución, más sencilla y que tal vez pueda funcionar, yo lo he probado en otros casos y me ha funcionado. No creo que sea para darle un negativo, cuando se intenta ayudar.

Comment: @PabloLozano segun este articulo si se puede utilizar `@Output EventEmitter`https://medium.com/@javifont/3-formas-de-comunicarse-entre-componentes-angular-b349ada25797

Comment: Gracias Pablo. Solo es otra manera de hacer las cosas.